# some variables remain null - stored procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, procedure

I am writing a small browser game with an InnoDB Database.
To automate the stuff that happens, when you build a new house, I wrote the following procedure. The problem with it is that every declared variable except "cycle_offset" is still NULL after the first SELECT, so the three following selects can't be executed without delivering NULL themselves.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_building //
CREATE PROCEDURE create_building(IN userID INT, IN buildingID INT)
BEGIN
--declare variables
DECLARE cycle_offset INT;
DECLARE res_1 INT;
DECLARE am_1 INT;
DECLARE res_2 INT;
DECLARE am_2 INT;
DECLARE res_3 INT;
DECLARE am_3 INT;
DECLARE u_am_1 INT;
DECLARE u_am_2 INT;
DECLARE u_am_3 INT;

--fill the values that belong to the certain type of building
SELECT  cycles * 10,
        res_1, 
        am_1, 
        res_2, 
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3 
INTO    cycle_offset,
        res_1,
        am_1, 
        res_2,
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3
FROM    build_cost 
WHERE   building = buildingID;

--select resources from user-fortune that were given in the build-cost
SELECT amount INTO u_am_1 FROM fortune WHERE resource = res_1;
SELECT amount INTO u_am_2 FROM fortune WHERE resource = res_2;
SELECT amount INTO u_am_3 FROM fortune WHERE resource = res_3;
--for each resource: if the resource is not null and the user has more resources left than needed 
--remove the "price" from the user's fortune
IF 
    ((res_1 IS NOT NULL) AND 
    (u_am_1 >= am_1))
THEN
    UPDATE fortune
    SET amount = (u_am_1 - am_1)
    WHERE resource = res_1 AND
          user = userID;
END IF;

IF 
    ((res_1 IS NOT NULL) AND 
    (u_am_2 >= am_2))
THEN
    UPDATE fortune
    SET amount = (u_am_2 - am_2)
    WHERE resource = res_2 AND
          user = userID;
END IF;

IF 
    ((res_1 IS NOT NULL) AND 
    (u_am_3 >= am_3))
THEN
    UPDATE fortune
    SET amount = (u_am_3 - am_3)
    WHERE resource = res_3 AND
          user = userID;
END IF;

--add the building into the users town

INSERT INTO town (user, building, cycle_start, level, in_construction)
VALUES (userID, 
        buildingID, 
        SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIME)+5)/10) * 10 + cycle_offset), 
        1,
        1);

--debugging purposes:
INSERT INTO debug (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l) VALUES (userID, buildingID, cycle_offset, res_1, am_1, res_2, am_2, res_3, am_3, u_am_1, u_am_2, u_am_3);
END //
```

The debug table always shows me that userID, buildingID and cycle_offset are not null, the rest is. You could think that the "build_cost"-table is empty, but running the query alone gives me this result (as expected):

```
SELECT  cycles * 10, res_1, am_1, res_2, am_2, res_3, am_3 
FROM    build_cost 
WHERE   building = 1;

+-------------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+
| cycles * 10 | res_1 | am_1 | res_2 | am_2 | res_3 | am_3 |
+-------------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+
|           0 |     4 |   50 |     5 |   50 |  NULL | NULL |
+-------------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+
```

Why are the values for cycles, res_1, am_1, res_2 and am_2 not stored in my declared variables if I run the procedure that contains this query?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are setting res_3 or am_3 to a value.

Comment: `SELECT  cycles * 10,
        res_1, 
        am_1, 
        res_2, 
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3 
INTO    cycle_offset, 
        res_1, 
        am_1, 
        res_2,
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3
FROM    build_cost 
WHERE   building = buildingID;`

It should happen here, or is this wrong?

Comment: Only if there are values in those columns.

Comment: there are, that's why I have given the example of the query itself (without the variable part)

Comment: Your example shows those columns as null.

Comment: yes they are that's right but not the point 

the point is that also `res_1`, `am_1`, `res_2` and `am_2` stay null which should NOT happen

Comment: That's not shown in your examples.

Comment: you misunderstand the example. the example shows that there should be values for this query, but if I call the procedure that contains this query it doesn't store the values (that should be there, except res_3 and am_3) into the variables which are needed to run another update statement.

Comment: I would suggest you show them in your question. IOW, what your source data is, what you actually see as a result, and what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in a debugger that MySQL interpretes

```
DECLARE cycle_offset INT;
DECLARE res_1 INT;
DECLARE am_1 INT;
DECLARE res_2 INT;
DECLARE am_2 INT;
DECLARE res_3 INT;
DECLARE am_3 INT;

SELECT  cycles * 10,
        res_1, 
        am_1, 
        res_2, 
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3 
INTO    cycle_offset,
        res_1,
        am_1, 
        res_2,
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3
FROM    build_cost 
WHERE   building = buildingID;
```

as

```
SELECT  cycles * 10,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
INTO    cycle_offset,
        res_1,
        am_1, 
        res_2,
        am_2, 
        res_3, 
        am_3
FROM    build_cost 
WHERE   building = buildingID;
```

because it, at least it looks like this, cannot differentiate between the variables and the table columns if they're namend equal.

Thanks for the effort, though